# .htaccess redirect to subfolder as well as https

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have been trying to modify my .htaccess file, but with mixed results.  Anybody who can assist me please?

What I am trying to achieve is the following:

- Redirect all http to https for my site.
- Redirect www.mydomain.com or mydomain.com to www.mydomain.com/forum or mydomain.com/forum

Edit:
I actually got it almost working the way I want it with the following code.  The only remaining issue is that when you enter http://www.soleil-noir.be for instance, it does not redirect to https

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?112th\.net
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.soleil-noir.be/forum%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, Please read [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before asking so that your question would be more likely to be answered than downvoted.

Comment: Please show your current .htaccess file

Comment: Original post updated with htaccess file